# Is there a way to scale a font only in one direction in wxpython (or in wxpython.richtext)

Tags: python, fonts, wxpython

I want to generate furigana (characters on top of the image, that represent the reading of characters below them) in `wxpython.richtext.RichTextCtrl`, but I couldn't find a way to scale a font in one direction like it is scaled on the image. The scaling on the image is a '.ass' subtitle format feature if that will help.

[image]

Comment: As someone who's read plenty of furigana: that looks absolutely terrible, just properly scale it instead?

Comment: @Mike For different words, furigana can have different height. That doesn't look better to me. I am considering using `<ruby>` tag from html5 and rendering it with [wx.html2.WebView](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.html2.WebView.html#phoenix-title-wx-html2-webview) or switching between kanji and hiragana in textctrl itself on click or on some shortcut.

Comment: Based on every single Japanese book in my bookcase, which is _a lot_: not really? Proper furigana is normal-aspect, just at a much smaller point size. The screenshot you showed I would consider a bug in whatever was rendering that text. As for using `<ruby>`: sensible idea but you may still need to write your own CSS rules (using flexbox, probably) to make sure it renders correctly. It's one of the least-properly-supported tags in the HTML element set.